# Is it good practice to use Throw shape to postpone message in Biztalk?

Tags: biztalk

At some point inside orchestration it's required to resend transaction after some period of time.
Is that okay to use Throw shape to make transaction failed, so it will be retried after some time in Port retrial
or it's better to use Loop/Wait shape for this ?

> You haven't really clarified why (the use-case) the message needs to
>   be resent.

Client requests us to resend transaction to web-service in case web-service returning "successful failed" error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't really clarified why (the use-case) the message needs to be resent, but in no scenario would I use `Throw` to control the flow through the orchestration.

**In an error scenario**

If you need to resend the message because it has failed to deliver, then the first stop is to [configure the send port to do retries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa578109.aspx), with a suitable delay interval (and note the backup transport option as well). It usually isn't necessary to do manual retries with orchestration loops. - Exceptions here include when the downstream service accepts the message and issues a custom retryable 'NACK' status - e.g. error indicating deadlock or timeout - which would then need to be checked and then the delay + loop scenario could be needed.

**Send to more than one consumer**

If you need to send the same message to another destination (after a delay) as part of the normal flow of the orchestration, then I would suggest using the [parallel actions shape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa559632.aspx) at the point where the flows diverge, and then use a delay shape on the second leg before sending to the second destination. If the message can be sent to multiple destinations at the same time, I would instead consider using [Send Port Groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee276901%28v=bts.10%29.aspx) to do this.

**Message Generator / Trigger / Scheduler**

If the purpose of the orchestration is to publish multiple messages (e.g. trigger messages) at defined intervals, then a publish, delay, and loop (and e.g. decrement a counter) orchestration would work fine.

Answer (score 2):

There is a good scenario outline for dealing with handling web service exceptions in this blog post: 
http://blog.codit.eu/post/2012/01/13/Best-Practices-for-consuming-Web-Services-from-within-BizTalk-Server.aspx

To implement the retry, you can either configure the send port to retry automatically, or put a loop shape with a delay in the error handler.